# intel webrtc 2.1.1 server connection issue

Tags: android, webrtc

I have an android app which makes peer-2-peer video and audio calls. It was using webrtc version 2.0, i was supposed to port it to version 2.1.1.

So i did replace the dependencies with the newer version. I had some errors but i fixed it - like some functions names changed and stuff like that - then the app is compiling and running good.

the issue here when i try to connect to intel server. The server receives the request along with name of the peer and authenticate it but never send the response no matter how long i wait. no failure or success message.

Comment: Without code and/or errors/stacktraces/logs it's kinda difficult to say, what's exactly going wrong.

Comment: @Arkadiy sorry, i did not know what to post with the question. There were a lot of code and there were not any errors. The server just did not respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me after several tries
when using intel webrtc server version 2.0 you use this url format to connect "http://0.0.0.0:8095/webrtc" => "http://ip:port/webrtc"
but when using version 2.1.1 you should use this format "http://0.0.0.0:8095" => "http://ip:port"
simply remove the "/webrtc" part